# Is Random Forest regression is good for this kind of regression problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

I am working with vehicle occupancy prediction and I am very much new to this, I have used random forest regression to predict the occupancy values.

[Jupyter notebook_Random forest](https://deepnote.com/project/Untitled-Python-Project-D6jNHahzTyCIYd_OcsM0bw/%2FRandom%20(1).ipynb)

I have around 48 M rows and I have used all the data to predict the occupancy, As the population and occupancy were normalized due to the higher numbers and I have predicted. I am sure the model is not good, how can I interpret the results from the RMSE and MAE. Also, the plot shows that it is not predicted well, Am I doing it in a correct way to predict the occupancy of the vehicles.

Kindly help me with the following,

1. Is Random forest regression is a good method to approach this problem?
2. How can I improve the model results?
3. How to interpret the results from the outcome

Comment: @JamesZ, Sorry I have updated the link. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Applying normalization to columns with using Tree based models are not going to effect the results.

Comment: If I were you, I would make a better flow to which we could test different preprocessing, and models with GridSearchCV to find best hyper-params. Begin by dropping all columns with unique rows. Do feature engineering on geolocation data. When using Tree based models don’t normalize your data. Else create a pipeline for data preprocessing.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel, Thank you for the explanation. Kindly can you explain to me more about the feature engineering on the geolocation data, what can be done to use that in the model ??

Comment: With geolocation, you can find anchors location. One project, predicting house prices, I selected locations(e.g. hospital, school, main stations to which I then calculated short distances. Thus houses in rich areas where grouped together as they shared similar distance to anchor location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is Random forest regression is a good method to approach this problem?

   -> The model is just a tool and can of course be used. However, no one can answer whether it is suitable or not, because we have not studied the distribution of data. It is suggested that you can try logistic regression, support vector machine regression, etc.
2. How can I improve the model results?

   -> I have several suggestions on how to improve: 1.Do not standardize without confirming whether the y value column has extreme values. 2.When calculating RMSE and Mae, use the original y value. 3.Deeply understand business logic and add new features. 4.Learn about data processing and Feature Engineering on the blog.
3. How to interpret the results from the outcome

   -> Bad results do not necessarily mean no value. You need to compare whether the model is better than the existing methods and whether it has produced more economic value. For example, error is loss, and accuracy is gain.

Hope these can help you.

Comment: I looked at your code and guessed that your y value has the nature of time series. Please try using the time series model. If you want more help, please share the standardized X and Y (the y value should not be too different from the real value)

Comment: If you want to save trouble, you can put the data on the AI platform of GCP, lol.

Comment: I'd be happy to help you.

Comment: Time series models: Arima, LSTM, TCN. You can learn these models on the blog first.

Comment: I suggest you try the time series model,Judge good or bad according to the results. Robust Model: This can only be answered after testing, and the data are diverse, temporal, seasonal, regional, etc. It is recommended that you build several regression models and time series models first, and judge the next optimization direction according to the results of these models.

Comment: You can desensitize the data and make it public on Google cloud disk.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of each column.

Comment: And how is the data collected，How is the data collected? Is it the data of a region collected? What is the envisaged goal？

Comment: Is your purpose to predict the daily occupation time of each ID, or the daily occupation time of the city, or other purposes.

Comment: It involves how you use it.

Comment: OK, I'll contact you if I need anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235858/discussion-between-lazy-and-aravinth).

Comment: So do you suggest to model with Arima model or any other time series model instead of Random forest regression ??

Answer (score 1):

You were recommended XGBoost based regressor so you could try as well LightGBM based one: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting RMSE of `0.002175863553610834` which is really close to zero. So, we can say that you have a good model. I don't think the model needs further improvement. If you still want to improve it, I think you should change the algorithm to `XGBoost` and use regularization and early stopping to avoid overfitting.

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 3000, learning_rate = 0.01, reg_alpha = 2, reg_lambda = 1, n_jobs = -1, random_state = 34, verbosity = 0)
    
evalset = [(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)]
model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric = 'rmse', eval_set = evalset, early_stopping_rounds = 5)
```

Comment: First Thank you for the response. The question is I should compare the mean of the occupancy with the RMSE to validate the model? From the plot, I feel it is not fitted well? How can I interpret the plot?  So the idea you are saying is instead of Random forest regressor use the XGBRegressor model is that it.

Comment: The low value is reflecting normalised target. You need to de-normalise to get actual error.

Comment: The closer it gets to zero the better. You can compare it to average-dummy model. Namely a model that constantly predict average score. Basicslly,  when tuning a same model, namely comparing same model with different hyper-parameters, or other models, you want to lower RSME as much as possible